# having issue with preg_replace and similar words in php

Tags: php, preg-replace

i want to search my string and replace some words by link to some page.
but i have problem with similar words like "Help" and "Help Me".
i want to link "Help Me"  not "Help".
this is my code:

```
$text="Please Help Me Fix This Issue!";
$AllTags=[];
$AllTags[]='Help';
$AllTags[]='Help Me';
    $tmp = array();
    foreach($AllTags as $term){
        $tmp[] = "/($term)/i";
    } 
echo preg_replace($tmp, '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $text);
```

Comment: If you only want to link "Help me", then don't include "Help" into your `AllTags` array.

Comment: Are you building the pattern dynamically? Or at design time? See http://ideone.com/Xyb7v2

Comment: Don't use an array with `preg_replace` because it processes the whole string once per item (with the changes of previous replacements). To do that you can: 1) sort searched items by string size (from large to small). 2) build a pattern with an alternation that includes all the sorted items (use `implode('|', $AllTags)`). 3) Process your string in one single pass with `preg_replace` with this pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the dynamic approach: sort the array by value length in a descending order, then `implode` with `|` into an alternation based pattern so that the longer parts will be matched first (remember that the first branch from the left that matches makes the regex stop analyzing the alternatives, see [*Remember That The Regex Engine Is Eager*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html#eager)).

Use

```
$text="Please Help Me Fix This Issue!";
$AllTags=[];
$AllTags[]='Help';
$AllTags[]='Help Me';
usort($AllTags, function($a, $b) {
    return strlen($b) - strlen($a);
});
echo preg_replace('~' . implode('|', $AllTags) . '~', '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $text);
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/o7XNqd).

The regex will look like [`~Help Me|Help~`](https://regex101.com/r/imhHcf/1). You might want to add word boundaries (`\b`) ([see demo](https://regex101.com/r/imhHcf/3)) or lookarounds like `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)` ([see demo](https://regex101.com/r/imhHcf/4)) to only match whole words later.

Comment: Instead of using `usort`, you can also do it with: `rsort($AllTags, SORT_FLAG_CASE | SORT_STRING);`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte:Yes, seems like [`rsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) will do the job, too.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your help.
this solution fixed my problem.