# Replace multiple strings without overlapping

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

I have PHP application in which I have to replace a whole bunch of strings with their respective links. Basically I get a list of possible replacements that looks something like that:

```
"Table 1" => "<a href='SOME_LINK'>Table 1</a>"
"Table 2" => "<a href='SOME_LINK'>Table 2</a>"
...
"Table 10" => "<a href='SOME_LINK'>Table 10</a>"
"Table 11" => "<a href='SOME_LINK'>Table 11</a>"
```

I go through each pair and I call `str_replace` which each couple of values. The problem is that even on the first pass I catch the `Table 10` strings as well as the `Table 1` strings and I replace both which is wrong. So I end up with result that has something like `<a href='SOME_LINK'>Table 1</a>0`. `Table 10` should not be replaced at all (unless later there's another pair that actually takes care of `Table 10`).

Any ideas for a work around? I though of adding a blank space after the search part of the string however it's possible to have something in the text like `Table 1,` which would then not match at all. I also considered using regular expressions to replace but not sure if there's a syntax there that would fix the issue above.

EDIT:
To improve the reading comprehension, here's expected input and output for this problem.
CONDITION:

```
"Table 1" => "<a href='SOME_LINK'>Table 1</a>"
"Table 10" => "<a href='SOME_LINK'>Table 10</a>"
```

INPUT:

```
We have some text here.
It has words like Table 1, Table 2 and also Table 10.
Those need to be replaced.
```

OUTPUT:

```
We have some text here.
It has words like <a href='SOME_LINK'>Table 1</a>, Table 2 and also <a href='SOME_LINK'>Table 10</a>.
Those need to be replaced.
```

Comment: Please do one thing just update your post with your input and expected result

Comment: See [Using preg_replace with career names and failing at it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42099833/having-issue-with-preg-replace-and-similar-words-in-php/42100111#42100111), it may help.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Very nice idea. I was thinking about sorting the items but the `|` addition was the part I was missing.

Comment: If that post answers your question, let's close this one as a dupe, shall we?

Comment: Gladly but please let me first try and see if I can make it work. I shall report back as soon as I'm done :)

Comment: I've added a working example to my answer, does it solve your problem?

Comment: @glaux Sort of, my specific problem turned out to be a bit more complicated than expected, but yes, sorting and then replacing only outside of links did most of the job. Thank you!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out! If my answer helped you, would you consider voting for it as well? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, how about sorting the array with replacements by key length descending and use regex to only replace strings that are not encapsulated by `<a>` tags?

That way you would replace `Table 10` before `Table 1`, and you wouldn't make any double replacements.

Edit:
Here is an example as requested

```
$input = "We have some text here.
  It has words like Table 1, Table 2 and also Table 10.
  Those need to be replaced.";

$replacements = [
  "Table 1" => "<a href='SOME_LINK'>Table 1</a>",
  "Table 2" => "<a href='SOME_LINK'>Table 2</a>",
  "Table 10" => "<a href='SOME_LINK'>Table 10</a>",
];

uksort($replacements, function($a, $b) {
  return strlen($b) - strlen($a);
});

foreach ( $replacements as $key => $value ) {
  $input = preg_replace('/([^>])'.$key.'/', '$1'.$value, $input);
}

// Show the result
print($input);
```

<s>This example require a space *before* the replacement key. It should be possible to modify it if this is prohibitive for the use case.</s>
I've updated the example to be agnostic to the character before the search key.

Comment: Can you please provide example of your idea?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the answer again because of the comment with more information.

You can search for the table with regex, for example, as PHP code:

```
$input = "We have some text here.
It haswords like Table 1, Table 2 and also Table 10.
Those need to be replaced.";

$output = preg_replace("/(Table 1)(?![\d])/U", "<a href=\"LINK HERE\">LINK TEXT</a>", $input);

echo "Input:<br>".$input."<br><br>Output:<br>".$output;
```

It seems PHP handles some regex options differently than I personally expected. This code worked for me in a test server (replacing "Table 1" with 2 or 10 replaced just the correct parts). If you want case-insensitive search, add i next to the U in the regex.

Comment: This is just an example to illustrate the issue. I do not have control over the input text, it's up to the user what kind of string they are going to use. I just get the list and the desired outcome, the rest is out of control.

Comment: You second solution doesn't seem to be working, it made a whole bunch of weird replacements not even hitting close to the bull's eye.